# How to reset a certains fields after submit in Formik

Tags: reactjs, formik

I am using Formik and I need to make this logic.
I am have a big form, and after submission I need to reset certain fields in this form

There is 2 buttton: Save and Save & New

1. **save** will save the data and redirect.
2. **Save & New** will save the data and reset the first two fields.

I tried to use:

- **resetForm** but it resets all the form
- **setValues** does not work
- **setFieldValues** prevents the api request
- **set values manually** also does not work

Here is the code

```
const initialValues = { value1: "", value2: "", value3: "", value4: "" };

<Formik
            initialValues={initialValues}
            enableReinitialize
            validationSchema={Schema}
            validateOnChange={false}
            validateOnBlur={false}
            onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting, resetForm }) => {
                props.addData(values);        // api request
                setSubmitting(false);
                // resetForm(initialValues); // this will reset all the form fields
                // values.value1 = "";       // does not work
            }}
        >
            {({ values, handleChange, handleSubmit, setFieldValue, errors }) => (
                <Form>
                    <Row>
                        <Field type="text" name="value1" />
                        <Field type="text" name="value2" />
                        <Field type="text" name="value3" />
                        <Field type="text" name="value4" />
                    </Row>
                    <StyledRow>
                        <Button
                            variant="outline-primary"
                            onClick={() => {
                                handleSubmit();
                                history.push("/tableOverview");
                            }}
                        >
                            Save
                        </Button>
                        <Button
                            variant="outline-primary"
                            onClick={() => {
                               handleSubmit();
                               // this prevents the api request, because of async code I guess
                               // setFieldValue("value1", "");
                               // setFieldValue("value2", "");
                            }
                        >
                            Save & New
                        </Button>
                    </StyledRow>
                </Form>
            )}
        </Formik>
```

Comment: may be you can rest the form and set the initialValues for all the fields you need the value, or use `setFieldsValue` and use `setSubmitting` to false, may be that will enable your button

Comment: thanks for your comment, but how to access `values` in `initialValues`?

Comment: may be this heps, https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-example-pf40m, will post an answer if it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On submitting the form, you can set whatever the values you dont want to peresist using `setFieldValue` and later `setSubmitting` to `false`, So that the values you want will be persisted and you can submit the form again

Please find the example codesandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-example-pf40m)